# Building an array of arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to get the following loop working to fill an array of arrays:

```
while (condition) {
[itemsArray fillFromDB];

if (! [checkArray containsObject:checkFlag]) {
  // Add existing itemsArray to myArray
  if (itemsArray.count) {
    // add the itemsArray to myArray and create a new instance of itemsArray
    [myArray addObject:itemsArray];
    [itemsArray release];
    NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  }
  [itemsArray addObject:myObject];
  [checkArray addObject:checkFlag];
} else {
  [itemsArray addObject:tmpEvent];
}  }
```

However I try to shape this loop it falls over the release of itemsArray

- when I use release (as above), the array does not re-initialise as a new instance with alloc. Whilst expecting emptyness, the next Object is added to the old array.
- when I use removeAllObjects, my Array is emptied and so is the array attached to myArray.

Where am I going in the wrong direction?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you going to accept any answers?

Comment: Sure, did I not respond to you that I did as you said? 
OK, just saw what you're saying, let me click the ticks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might place:

```
itemsArray = nil;
```

after the `release` message, to ensure that you're not pointing to an old instance.

**EDIT**

Looking at this again, you have:

```
NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

This is scoped within the `if` statement.

So take out `NSMutableArray` and just use:

```
itemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Hi Alex, tried it, but leads to an "[NSCFArray count]: method sent to an uninitialized mutable array object'" error ...

Answer (score 0):

Don't write `NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`--you're re-declaring the variable in the scope of the `if` statement, so outside the `if` statement, `itemsArray` will still refer to the old value (I'm not sure why the compiler isn't complaining).  You can just say `itemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` instead.

You also might want to use autorelease, to simplify, as well.

Answer (score 0):

The others have found the problem, but have created a new problem. The first time you create the mutable array, you need to use `NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`. Then, after, you can `release` and use `itemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`. It is important that the first one (the one that creates the pointer) occurs only once, and the rest can occur as many times as desired.

EDIT:
You could write `NSMutableArray *itemsArray;` before the `if` statement, and then use `itemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` in the `if` statement.

Comment: Hi jrtc27, this is how I have it now, just not visible in the above code sample, thanks a lot